# ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API can't capture POST value

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I tried to capture the data sent to my Web API using Wireshark. This one works fine:
[image: Using C# HttpClient]

While this one can only fetch those that are in the URL but not the body. It can only be fetched as empty string or null.
[image: Using Android/Java HttpUrlConnection]

Comment: Just as a suggestion, have you tried 'Fiddler' instead of WireShark to capture http connections?

Comment: just tried it but it looks like it can't capture inbound requests.